# Appending TU matrix with the identity or zero matrix still give us another TU matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

If $A$ was a totally unimodular matrix, then show the matrix obtained by augmenting with the identity matrix $[A|I]$ is TU. Also show the matrix obtained by augmenting with the zero matrix matrix [$A|0]$ is TU.

I know TU matrix implies $A$ has to have all entries of $[0,1,-1]$. Does augmenting mean elementary row operation? If so, can any one provide some brief hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a totally unimodular matrix.

Consider appending a single column of standard unit basis to a totally unimodular matrix. Let $B= [A, e_i]$.

Now, let's consider a submatrix of $B$. If it doesn't involve the last column, the determinant is clearly $0,1$, or $-1$.

If it involves the last coumn, then let's perform Laplace expansion along the last column, it will be either be $0$ or $c$ times determiant of submatrix of $A$ where $c \in \{1,-1\}$.

Hence appending a single column consisting of standard unit basis preserve the totally unimodular property.

Comment: is there a simpler solution of not using laplace? i have not encountered laplace yet thank you

Comment: how do you compute determinant?

Comment: i compute determinant using the determinants of submatrices (the most basic way)

Comment: I have a second question on what exactly is [A 0] is it just equal to B you mentioned?; i know [A i] is the "inverse" of A

Comment: I believe you know [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion), just that you do not know it has a name. Would you like to explain the notation $[A, 0]$, $[A ,i]$, I don't understand them. Try to use mathjax.

Comment: Sorry, my bad and I just learned laplce a long time ago so my apologies that I do not recall; [A I] is augmented matrix by identity matrix [A 0] is by zero matrix

Comment: Ok, I was editing your question and now I can guess what do you mean. If you append a zero columns, if you submatrix include the column, try to expand along that column, you will get zero. Just append a single column first, then expand along that column to perform induction. The argument for appending the whole matrix is by induction. Here is a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide.

Comment: thank you for editing! can you explain what $[A|0]$ is really? is it just appending 0 columns onto A? side note: i got laplace expansion confused with transformation so not laplace expansion makes sense! thank you

Comment: yes, just appending $0$ block, for the other case, it is just appending the identity matrix.

Comment: so if i was to use your answer from above, i would change $e_i$ to a zero column and that would mean B would have a zero determinant along laplace expansion of the zero column every time? And thus B has to be TU since its det is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106582/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-james-black).